# route saying forbidden although i issued user jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, thunderclient

Using thunderclient (similar to postman) i cant access this employee api which requires a jwt, even though i confirm i am already authorized. Here is my code:
authController:

```
const usersDB = {
  users: require("../model/users.json"),
  setUsers: function (data) {
    this.users = data;
  },
};

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

const handleLogin = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, pwd } = req.body;
  if (!user || !pwd)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Username and password are required." });

  const foundUser = usersDB.users.find((person) => person.username === user);
  console.log(foundUser);
  if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(401);
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(pwd, foundUser.password);
  if (match) {
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      { username: foundUser.username },
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "60s" }
    );
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
      { username: foundUser.username },
      //   we need our secret from env file as well to make our jwt
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "1d" }
    );
    const otherUsers = usersDB.users.filter(
      (person) => person.username !== foundUser.username
    );
    const currentUser = { ...foundUser, refreshToken };

    usersDB.setUsers([...otherUsers, currentUser]);
    await fsPromises.writeFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "..", "model", "users.json"),
      JSON.stringify(usersDB.users)
    );
    res.cookie("jwt", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      ameSite: "None",
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });
    res.json({ accessToken });
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
};

module.exports = { handleLogin };
```

sever.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = require("./config/corsOptions");
const { logger } = require("./middleware/logEvents");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const verifyJWT = require("./middleware/verifyJWT");


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500;

app.use(logger);

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./public")));

// routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/root"));
app.use("/register", require("./routes/register"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/refresh", require("./routes/refresh"));

app.use(verifyJWT);
app.use("/employees", require("./routes/api/employees"));

app.all("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404);
  if (req.accepts("html")) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "404.html"));
  } else if (req.accepts("json")) {
    res.json({ error: "404 Not Found" });
  } else {
    res.type("txt").send("404 not found");
  }
});

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

verifyJWT middleware:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (!authHeader) return res.sendStatus(401);
  console.log(authHeader);
  // bearer token, hence bearer space 1, 1 is the token
  const token = authHeader.split("")[1];
  // decoded info from the jwt
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    // 403 is forbidden
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = decoded.username;
    next();
  });
};

module.exports = verifyJWT;
```

so if i for example
http://localhost:3500/auth (post) and login with a user and pwd, my res does log an access token, and if i try to use that inside

http://localhost:3500/employees (get) i get forbidden. not sure what i am missing here

i tried console.logging to see if i had foundUser, which i did, so not sure why i cant get into this route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting by empty string, it would divide every character, try spliting by space:

```
const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
```